# Autodesk forge view additional 3d views and optioning

Tags: 3d, autodesk, revit, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In revit you are able to save multiple 3d views and also have design optioning.

[image: example of revit 3d views]

[image: design option picker]

In the basic Autodesk Forge Viewer it appears that only the main 3d model view is brought in and I cannot see where I can pick from the design options. Is this data available using the API and if so how could I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mikako points out, the C4R A360 Collaboration for Revit add-in implements this functionality.

Furthermore, external developers can write their own Revit add-in to programmatically select views by using the C4R functionality, since it is exposed by the `ExportViewSelectorAddin.dll` component, which is installed as part of the C4R package.

More information is provided in The Building Coder discussion on [Selecting RVT 3D Views for Forge Translation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/07/selecting-views-for-forge-translation.html).

Answer (score 0):

For additional views, this post explains what is possible and what is not: 
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/selecting-views-to-publish-revit-project-on-a360/

In a nutshell, no API in viewer side, but selecting additional view is possible using C4R add-ins. Design option is not currently supported.